# Not Getting time in dd/mm/yyyy format and getting time less than expected time in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

im converting date to tostring but im not getting the date in the correct format and also im getting the time 5 hours, 31 minutes and 10 seconds late than expected time. i need india kolkata timezone.

```
actual time - 2017-02-26T17:45:34.851Z
getting time- 2/26/2017, 11:16:44 PM


public string UpdatedTime { get; set; }
```

controller code

```
BinDetailsViewModel binModel = new BinDetailsViewModel();
binModel.UpdatedTime = Convert.ToDateTime(bin.timestamp.ToString()).ToString();
```

Comment: ok  im checking.....

Comment: Why are you converting a `DateTime` to a string anyway? Just change your model property to `DateTime` and you won't have this problem. You are going `DateTime` to `string` to `DateTime` back to `string` again, all in a single line of code!

Comment: @DavidG You are right. I was about to suggest the same

Comment: Which format do you need: `2/26/2017, 11:16:44 PM` or `2017-02-26T17:45:34.851Z`?

Comment: 2/26/2017, 11:16:44 PM  with local time - India..kolkata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your time is in UTC so you can convert it to local time by using `.ToLocalTime()`.

And you need to provide the date time format in `.ToString()` method.

```
DateTime.ToLocalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can use as below;

```
binModel.UpdatedTime = Convert.ToDateTime(bin.timestamp).ToLocalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: binModel.UpdatedTime = Convert.ToDateTime(("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToLocalTime();

Comment: @Swapna is bin.timestamp a string in your model?

Comment: saying cultural info not exist. do i need to add localization refernce

Comment: @Swapna, add `using System.Globalization;`

Comment: i got it but its not showing AM and PM , how to show AM and PM.?i was looking for local time with AM and PM